# Trouble doing multiLabel-classification

Tags: python, pytorch, multilabel-classification

I am a student and I am doing multi-label classification homework.
There is 28 labels,but only 3or4 of them always get high probability.Why?
Maybe something wrong in data pre-processing?
I wanna every label can get the chance to output.
But only a few stable labels can get the chance.

```py
def Predict_alpha(outputs, alpha=0.4):
    predic = torch.sigmoid(outputs)
    zero = torch.zeros_like(predic)
    for i, x in enumerate(predic):
        for j, y in enumerate(x):
            if y >= alpha:
                zero[i][j] = 1
    return zero.cpu()
```

The code above is to find topK labels.
The code below is to train BERT model to do multilable-classification.

```
def train(config, model, train_iter, dev_iter, test_iter, is_write):
    start_time = time.time()
    model.train()

    # bert算法
    param_optimizer = list(model.named_parameters())
    no_decay = ['bias', 'LayerNorm.bias', 'LayerNorm.weight']
    optimizer_grouped_parameters = [
        {'params': [p for n, p in param_optimizer if not any(nd in n for nd in no_decay)], 'weight_decay': 0.01},
        {'params': [p for n, p in param_optimizer if any(nd in n for nd in no_decay)], 'weight_decay': 0.0}]
    # BertAdam implements weight decay fix,
    # BertAdam doesn't compensate for bias as in the regular Adam optimizer.
    optimizer = AdamW(optimizer_grouped_parameters, lr=config.learning_rate, eps=1e-8)

    # 学习率指数衰减，每次epoch：学习率 = gamma * 学习率
    scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(optimizer,
                                                num_warmup_steps=0,
                                                num_training_steps=len(train_iter) * config.num_epochs)
    total_batch = 0  # 记录进行到多少batch
    dev_best_loss = float('inf')
    last_improve = 0  # 记录上次验证集loss下降的batch数
    flag = False  # 记录是否很久没有效果提升
    if is_write:
        writer = SummaryWriter(
            log_dir="{0}/{1}__{2}__{3}__{4}".format(config.log_path, config.batch_size, config.pad_size,
                                                    config.learning_rate,
                                                    time.strftime('%m-%d_%H.%M', time.localtime())))
    for epoch in range(config.num_epochs):
        print('Epoch [{}/{}]'.format(epoch + 1, config.num_epochs))
        true_trainop=0
        for i, (trains, labels) in enumerate(train_iter):
            outputs = model(trains)
            model.zero_grad()
            loss = Loss(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            predic = Predict(outputs)
            y_type, y_true, y_pred = metrics._classification._check_targets(labels.data.cpu().numpy(), predic.data.cpu().numpy())
            differing_labels = metrics._classification.count_nonzero(y_true - y_pred, axis=1)
            score=differing_labels <= 2
            #print(score)
            if score==True:
                true_trainop+=1

            if total_batch % 100 == 0:
                # 每多少轮输出在训练集和验证集上的效果
                true = labels
                predic = Predict(outputs)
                train_oe = OneError(outputs, true)
                train_acc = true_trainop/(i+1)
                train_pre, train_hl = APH(true.data.cpu().numpy(), predic.data.cpu().numpy())[1:3]

                dev_acc, dev_pre, dev_hl, dev_oe, dev_loss = evaluate(config, model, dev_iter)
                if dev_loss < dev_best_loss:
                    dev_best_loss = dev_loss
                    torch.save(model.state_dict(), config.save_path)
                    improve = '*'
                    last_improve = total_batch
                else:
                    improve = ''
                time_dif = get_time_dif(start_time)
                msg = 'Iter: {0:>6}, Train=== Loss: {1:>6.2}, Acc: {2:>6.2%}, Pre: {3:>6.2%}, HL: {4:>5.2} OE: {' \
                      '5:>6.2%}, Val=== Loss: {6:>5.2}, Acc: {7:>6.2%}, Pre: {8:>6.2%}, HL: {9:>5.2}, ' \
                      'OE: {10:>6.2%}, Time: {11} {12} '
                print(msg.format(total_batch, loss.item(), train_acc, train_pre, train_hl, train_oe,
                                 dev_loss, dev_acc, dev_pre, dev_hl, dev_oe, time_dif, improve))
                if is_write:
                    writer.add_scalar('loss/train', loss.item(), total_batch)
                    writer.add_scalar("acc/train", train_acc, total_batch)
                    writer.add_scalar("pre/train", train_pre, total_batch)
                    writer.add_scalar("oe/train", train_oe, total_batch)
                    writer.add_scalar("hamming loss/train", train_hl, total_batch)
                    writer.add_scalar("loss/dev", dev_loss, total_batch)
                    writer.add_scalar("acc/dev", dev_acc, total_batch)
                    writer.add_scalar("pre/dev", dev_pre, total_batch)
                    writer.add_scalar("oe/dev", dev_oe, total_batch)
                    writer.add_scalar("hamming loss/dev", dev_hl, total_batch)
                model.train()
            total_batch += 1
            if total_batch - last_improve > config.require_improvement:
                # 验证集loss超过1000batch没下降，结束训练
                print("No optimization for a long time, auto-stopping...")
                flag = True
                break
        scheduler.step()  
        if flag:
            break
    if is_write:
        writer.close()
    evaluate_test(config, model, test_iter)
    return
```

The code below is to predict lables of the testdata.

```
def evaluate_test(config, model, data_iter, test=False):
    file_path = 'D:/pythonProject/dlproj/proj_data/'
    labels_df = pd.read_csv(file_path + 'ccpt_id2ccpt.csv', header=None)
    model.eval()
    loss_total = 0
    predict_all = []
    labels_all = []
    with torch.no_grad():
        for texts, labels in data_iter:
            ans=[]
            outputs = model(texts)
            oe = OneError(outputs.data.cpu(), labels.data.cpu())
            loss = Loss(outputs, labels)
            loss_total += loss
            labels = labels.data.cpu().numpy()
            predic = Predict(outputs.data).numpy()
            #labels_all = np.append(labels_all, labels)
            predict_all = np.append(predict_all, predic)
            #print(predic)
            for i,idx in enumerate(predic[0]):
                if idx==1:
                    ans.append(labels_df.loc[i,0])
            print(ans)
    return
```

Comment: Welcome.  We can't really tell you why your code isn't working if we don't have your code.  Why do you think the results should be different?

Comment: Is your dataset balanced? If your training dataset contains mostly examples of a few classes then the model will be biased to predict those classes.

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment@TimRoberts! There is a lot codes and I don't know which part meet wrong. I show my train and test part above. And when I think about the output label, I think it's not explainable. If I do the classifacation, the results must be different from the model does.

Comment: Thanks for you comment@SembeiNorimaki! I think it's balanced. Do you think some meaningless words in the traindata can affect the output? (I am doing Chinese text multi-label classfication)